# Developing similar apps, games, etc. on Google Play Store or App Store

Tags: software, patents, theft, professional-ethics

I am planning to develop similar apps, games, etc., which may free or non-free, on Google Play Store or App Store and to earn money with methods such as ads, sale on same stores, etc.

To be clearer I'll develop [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cf.mathgamesmentalcalculationmathematics), after seeing [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miniklerogreniyor.quiz.kids.math) : )

However, I don't know whether they are patented or it is considered as non-ethical, copy, theft, plagiarism, etc. and I see tons of similar apps, games, etc. on these stores.

What should I think in this case?

Is it legal what I am planning?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you copy. It's worth noting that it doesn't matter whether or how you make money off of this.

Apps on the Play Store are likely to be copyrighted. They may also include trademarks.

However, "ideas" cannot be copyrighted, only actual works. Game mechanics themselves are also not copyrightable (this is a good thing- imagine if no company was allowed to make an fps because Doom exists).

If you want to make a game about flinging things at little forts to collapse them on the people inside, go for it. The fact that it is a clone of Angry Birds would not be enough for Rovio to sue you.

There are copyrighted or trademarked aspects of games that you would need to avoid, including (this is by no means exhaustive):

- Sprites and other artwork
- Music and sound effects
- Titles (trademarked)
- Characters (trademarked)
- Dialogue
- Game code

Note that this only applies to the legal aspect. App stores may have other policies which are beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Characters are likely also subject to copyright protection (perhaps even more likely than they are to be trademarked)